# Is there any best way to say rather than "stronger and stiffer"

Tags: word-request

In Grammarly, I typed the following sentence, and then it showed the word "stronger" as an invalid word choice.

> The fiber optics are stronger and stiffer than the cable that helps communicate.

[image]

your suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I'm not sure why it rejects _stronger_, but surely _fibre optics_ is the technology being used, not the physical cable? Try _fiber optic cable is stronger_.

Comment: If it only rejects the combination "stronger and stiffer" but accepts either word separately, then Grammarly is wrong. I would also agree with @KateBunting's comment.

Comment: Also, "*fiber optics **is**...*" since it's a technology, and therefore uncountable. Grammarly makes lots of mistakes, and here on ELL SE we regularly get questions about them. Don't go premium.

Comment: I’m closing this question because it's based on an incorrectly reported error by a grammar checker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although Grammarly is not always right, in this case I agree that “stronger and stiffer” is an odd choice of words for describing a cable, especially the “stiffer” part.

In my opinion, a better choice would be “more durable.”